# How to add coinbase transaction with libblkmaker

Tags: block, coinbase-transaction

I currently trying to develop a simple Bitcoin miner in c++ for a project on my university. For parsing the 'getblocktemplate'-data I'm using [libblkmaker](https://github.com/bitcoin/libblkmaker).
Now I have to build the coinbase transaction for the 'blktmpl', but I don't really know how.

**Anyone knows how to add a coinbase transaction to the block-template with 'libblkmaker'?**

**And how do I add my bitcoin address to this?**

Thanks for your help,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

To set a generating address, use [`set_generate_addr`](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/blob/bfgminer/miner.c#L1343). [`blkmk_init_generation3`](https://github.com/bitcoin/libblkmaker/blob/master/blkmaker.c#L50) may also be what you're looking for.

The author of that library also wrote a miner, [BFGMiner](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/), that uses his library. Look at how he calls these `libblkmaker` function to add a coinbase transaction to the block header in [`miner.c`](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/blob/bfgminer/miner.c).

Comment: I also fund the function 'blkmk_init_generation' and it seems to work. Do I also have to call 'blkmk_append_coinbase_safe2'?